# Gtkmm : how to open an .odp file ( of open office ) in a gtk window

Tags: gtkmm

I want to open say test.odp file is a gtk window. I know how to open a PDF file but don't know about odp file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are [several ways to convert](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60778/how-can-i-convert-an-odt-file-to-a-pdf) things that libreoffice can open into a PDF. You could use that to create a temporary PDF and open that.

I don't think there exists any sort of library that would permit you to edit an ODP, because that type of operation is complex enough that it deserves a dedicated application.

If I had an application that wanted to provide an ODT to someone I would probably consider alternative approaches. If you are generating or downloading an ODP from somewhere, give the user a "Save As..." dialog. That way they know where to find it, and can open it themselves with whatever program they feel is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

An .odp file is basically a zip archive which contains multiple files with medadata, and some files with the actual data.
[Wikipedia](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FOpenDocument%23Beispiel) has an example for this. Based on the wikipedia article, you could write a library that can convert .odp files to pdf files, and then display the pdf you generated in your gtk window.
Another solution : You could start LibreOffice or OpenOffice from your gtk application, with the path to the .odp file as argument. Include the cstdlib header, then modify the following code to your needs :

```cpp
path = "/path/to/file.odp"; // e.g. the contents of a Gtk::Entry could be assigned  to this variable
exit_code = std::system("libreoffice " + path); // if you have using namespace std; in your code, remove the std::
// ...
// do something with exit_code (if you want)
```

Documentation for the std::system function can be found on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)